# Syntax error when defining table with ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, constraints

I'm trying to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in a FK constraint in MS Access 2007, but I'm getting an error on table definition:

> SQL Error: Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause.

Here's the code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Area (
    Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    AreaType__Id int NOT NULL, 
    Tbl1 text(31) NOT NULL, 
    Tbl2__Id int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT UK_Area_1 UNIQUE (Tbl1, Container__Id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Area_1 FOREIGN KEY (AreaType__Id) REFERENCES AreaType (Id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Area_2 FOREIGN KEY (Tbl2__Id) REFERENCES Tbl2 (Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

What am I doing wrong? I looked at the Access Help, and my syntax seems correct. I've tried removing the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` portion, but got the same error. I've also tried using the default PK field for the referenced table (`REFERENCES Container` instead of `REFERENCES Container (Id)`), but again got the same error. I also searched SO, but didn't find much useful info for my situation. It's got to be something simple, but I'm not seeing it at the moment.

**EDIT**

It's worth mentioning, that the table definition was working properly exactly as it is, except without the `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` part. Only after adding the `CASCADE` parts did the error appear.

**EDIT 2**

In an attempt to pinpoint the problem, here is new test code that demonstrates the error:

THIS WORKS:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
    Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    T1__Id int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT FK_T2_1 FOREIGN KEY (T1__Id) REFERENCES T1 (Id)
);
```

THIS GIVES ERROR:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
    Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    T1__Id int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT FK_T2_1 FOREIGN KEY (T1__Id) REFERENCES T1 (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Can anyone replicate the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CREATE` statement is valid Access DDL, but *must* be executed with ADO.

Here is an Immediate window session which demonstrates the problem ...

```vb
strSql = "CREATE TABLE T2 (" & vbCrLf & _
"    Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " & vbCrLf & _
"    T1__Id int NOT NULL, " & vbCrLf & _
"    CONSTRAINT FK_T2_1 FOREIGN KEY (T1__Id) REFERENCES T1 (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE" & vbCrLf & _
");"

' executing that statement with DAO triggers error 3289,
' "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."
' (CurrentDb.Execute is a DAO Method)
CurrentDb.Execute strSql ' DAO -> fail

' CurrentProject.Connection.Execute is an ADO method,
' so this attempt executes without error
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql ' ADO -> OK
```

Note if you were trying to execute the statement from the Access query designer, that also uses DAO so would trigger error 3289 too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, The names `Container` and `Name` I used originally were actually "dummy" names to simplify the code. I've changed them to generic names in my question and added a comment to clarify that the code was working without the `CASCADE` parts. Any other ideas?

Comment: I created `AreaType` and `Container` tables, then successfully executed the statement as written in my answer in Access 2007.  I have no idea why it fails for you.

Comment: Please see new code above. Can you execute both cases successfully?

Comment: @neizan The previous version of this answer also worked for me using `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`.  I suspect it failed for you because you were using a different method to execute the statement.

Comment: You're right. I was using `CurrentDb.Execute`. I'll try the other.

Comment: It worked using `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`. Thanks for sticking with me!

Answer (score 3):

The OP's problem has been solved a long time ago (see HansUp's answer); however, this answer might be useful to someone else getting the same error message.

I got the same error because I tried to reference a table named "User". Since user is a reserved word (apparently), this failed. The resolution is to enclose reserved names in brackets (`[User]`).

```sql
ALTER TABLE UserSetting
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserSetting_User
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES [User] (UserID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 1):

The referential integrity syntax that works for me is the following:

```
create table Area (
  ID autoincrement primary key
, AreaTypeID long not null
  constraint Area_AreaTypeID
  references AreaType (ID)
, Tbl1 varchar(31) not null
, Tbl2ID long not null
  constraint Area_Tbl2ID
  references Tbl2 (ID)
  on update cascade
  on delete cascade
, constraint Area_UK unique (
    Tbl1
  , ContainerID
  )
)
```

The names themselves aren't very important, but as you can see I avoid giving columns the same name as other tables to avoid confusing the database engine.

Also I would say that if the Tbl2 ID column is an autoincrement column, the `on update` clause is redundant because obviously the numerical ID is never going to change.

Comment: You're right about the `ON UPDATE` being redundant. It wasn't in my original code, but "worked its way in" as I tried to get the code to execute properly.

Comment: Please see new code above. I have also tried using names like `Id1` and `Id2` to avoid same-named columns in different tables, but the result was the same, I still get the error.

Comment: @neizan - let me know if my syntax (including data type `long` instead of `int`) works for you.

Comment: I tried with `long` and using your syntax, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @neizan - what are you using to run your queries? I always use `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "create table ..."`.

Comment: I am using `CurrentDb.Execute`. I'll try `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` and see what happens. HansUp was also using that, so it looks promising.

Comment: It finally worked. I wish I could accept yours and HansUp's answers, since you both helped me find the root problem within one minute of each other. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @neizan - hah, fair enough. HasUp is _really_ good. In fact I subscribe to his StackOverflow activity RSS feed to get a daily dose of Access knowledge.