# Struggling With a Basic Question in MS Access - I'm New

Tags: ms-access

I'm using SQL in MS Access

Here's the question:
Create a table based on the following information:

Given: Employee (EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentName, PhoneNumber, Email)
EmployeeNumber is Primary Key
DepartmentName is Foreign Key
Email is an Alternate Key

Cascade Updates but not deletions from Department(another table) to Employee

Based on what's being asked and my code, what did I do wrong and why am I getting that error?

THANK YOU

My Code in Access
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zfw7.jpg

Comment: Does this address your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839422/sql-learner-ms-access-2013-on-update-cascade-and-on-delete-cascade

Comment: So then that means it can’t be done in access? Because I was given a school assignment to do this in access so does that mean my professor was wrong and it can’t be done?

Comment: Hey, try this.  Remove the on update on delete section.  Create your tables.  Then go to design view, click Relationships,>Edit Relationships and select the table (I only see Departments there), then click the checkboxes for cascade deletes.

Comment: Thank you! I did that. My problem is I have an exam and when I do it that way it doesn’t show up in the code

Comment: Hey, I think I see how to do it.  Seems like the developer option is missing from the customize ribbon options in late versions of Access, but you can still press CTL+G to bring up the editior.  From there, add a module, then do something like this: https://imgur.com/wqqOrYB  Sorry for the image, but the question was closed, so I can't add an answer.